# After uninstall app and after some months again install app then push notifications receive or not?

Tags: android, testing, push-notification, manual-testing

There is lots of test scenarios for test cases to test push notification for Android app.and I refere  this  [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/what-are-must-test-cases-to-test-push-notification-for-android-app)

But my question is 'user installed app and registered in app and then uninstalled it,then push notifications which was send to that user will receive after one month when user again install app?

Comment: On re-installation device Token will be change . Hence NO .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you uninstall the application your token will expire ...so if you want to send the push notification to particular user then it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

No. User should not receive the past push notifications (Which was sent when the app is uninstalled).

The user should receive push notifications which are triggered when the app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask yourself, as a user, if you would like so many push notifications from the past month bombard your phone as soon as you re-install the app and log-in. This functionality will harm not only UX but the developers as well.